# Finding the number of permutations of the first hundred integers so that they satisfy a divisibility criterion.

Tags: combinatorics

How many permutations $a_1,a_2,a_3,..., a_{100}$ of the integers from $1$ to $100$ are there such that none of the sums

$$a_1,a_1+a_2,a_1+a_2+a_3,\dots ,a_1+a_2+\dots + a_{100}$$

are divisible by 3.

I tried considering $a_1$ as $3m+1$ and $3m+2$ but they make many cases themselves.Any hints?

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking

Comment: You mean such that $a_1,a_1+a_2,\cdots$ aren't multiplies of $3$?

Comment: @kingW3 Yes I mean that.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** For a moment forget all the multiples of $3$ that appear in the sequence. This leaves 34 numbers that leave a reminder  of $1$  and $33$ numbers that leave a reminder $2$. So this problem is all about find the number of sequences containing $34$ one's and $33$ two's such that the sum of the first $k$ numbers is not divisible by $3$.

(After finding such a sequence you need to insert the multiples of $3$ into the sequence. This will produce all the sequences that are sought for.)

The sequence either begins with $2$ or $1$.

If it begins with $1$ then the sequence will have to proceed as follows,

$1,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2 \dots$

That should give you a start.